# cucumber - [31mFailed scenarios:[0m Console message

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

I have created a java-Cucumber test suite and its integrated in Jenkin and works fime.

Mu Question is when any script fails. I am getting below message in console.

> [**31**mFailed scenarios:[0m
>   [31mfeatures/XXXXXX.feature:5 [**0m**# Scenario: XXXXX Scenarios Outline
>
> 20 Scenarios ([31**m1** failed[**0m**, [32m19 passed[0m)
>   52 Steps ([**31m**1 failed[0m, [**36m**1 skipped[0m, [32m50 passed[0m)
>   1m22.342s.

What is that 31m, 0m, 36m is about. Can I turn that off from my console else highlight with some color. Please help !! Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add your cucumber options to the question?

Comment: Have a look at this - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/issues/18

Comment: @RunWith(ExtendedCucumber.class)
@ExtendedCucumberOptions(jsonReport = "target/cucumber.json", detailedReport = true, detailedAggregatedReport = true, overviewReport = true, toPDF = true, outputFolder = "target")
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "json:target/cucumber.json", "usage:target/cucumber-usage.json" }, features = {
        "classpath:features/" }, glue = {
                "com.package" }, tags = { "@sometagname" })

Comment: BTW, I am getting this issue when I try to execute through MAC terminal not through eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Those are non printable character and markup. To turn off it, you can set cucumber option monochrome as true.

This option can either set as true or false. If it is set as true, it means that the console output for the Cucumber test are much more readable. And if it is set as false, then the console output is not as readable as it should be. It is false by default.

```
package cucumberTest;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(

        features = "Feature"

        ,glue={"stepDefinition"}

        ,monochrome = true

        )

public class TestRunner {

}
```

Comment: Also worth noting, those control codes are what sets the text colour. For example, ESC[31m is red text, 32 is green (the ESC character is invisible, of course). If you see the codes it means your terminal doesn't support them.

Comment: If you are running from the command line, you can provide the argument `--monochrome` to run without colors. The codes you are seeing are [ANSI color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors). You should be able to configure your system to interpret them correctly, but I cannot find how atm.