# How to remove special characters from gitlab trace log API

Tags: c#, unicode, gitlab, ascii, ansi-escape

I am calling gitlab trace api to get the job raw log. Output contains some
unicode/ANSI characters like \u001b, 1m etc . How do i remove all those characters? I
tried many different Regex but none is removing all the character set. Is there a way to
read raw log without special characters or remove them by using RegEx.

```
  Gitlab API:  https://gitlab.some.com/api/v4/projects/110506/jobs/80341714/trace

   **Response** : [0KRunning with gitlab-runner 14.10.1 (f761588f)[0;m
     [0KRunning with gitlab-runner 14.10.1 (f761588f)[0;m
     [0K  on buildops-shared-linux-pks-s3b-main-10026789-gitlab-runner-vl58t 
    z4p2xwH_[0;m
    section_start:1655122076:resolve_secrets
    [0K[0K[36;1mResolving secrets[0;m[0;m
    section_end:1655122076:resolve_secrets
    [0Ksection_start:1655122076:prepare_executor
    [0K[0K[36;1mPreparing the "kubernetes" executor[0;m[0;m
    [0KUsing Kubernetes namespace: glr-shared[0;m
    [0KUsing Kubernetes executor with image harbor.dell.com/devops-images/traditional-
    [0K[0K[36;1mPreparing environment[0;m[0;m
```

I am using C# code and while debugging i can see that it is decoding those special characters to \u001b;[0K [1m; etc like this : "\001b[0KRUnning on the runner"

```
    _commonService.GetGitlabHeaders(errorLog.AuthToken));
    var section_description  = await 
    msg2.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() ;
    section_description = 
    Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(section_description,"\x1B(?:[@-Z\\- 
    _] |[[0 -?][-/][@-~])", ""),"\a","");
```

Comment: Not a dupe target, but related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725838/cucumber-31mfailed-scenarios0m-console-message Does gitlab have a way to view the logs without colors or non-printable characters?

Answer (score 2):

At the end of a log file created via the gitlab trace api, you might see something like this:

```
 section_end:1668970031:step_script^M^[[0Ksection_start:1668970031:cleanup_file_variables^M^[[0K^[[0K^[[36;1mCleaning up file based variables^[[0;m
^[[0;msection_end:1668970031:cleanup_file_variables^M^[[0K^[[32;1mJob succeeded
^[[0;m
```

This removes most of the ANSI color codes like ^[[0;m.

```
sed 's/\x1B\[[0-9;]*[mK]//g' temp.log | tr -d $'\r'
```

Update 2022-11-21: As suggested by @KatrinLeinweber, GitLab support uses this regex:

```
sed "s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g;s,\x0D\x0A,\x0A,g" temp.log
```

This works like a charm. But it does leave only the section start and section end tags:

```
... other log content ...
section_end:1669039557:step_script
section_start:1669039557:cleanup_file_variables
Cleaning up file based variables
section_end:1669039557:cleanup_file_variables
Job succeeded
```

They  are related to the collapsable and expandable sections in the GitLab GUI
[image: collapsable and expandable sections in GitLab]

Update 2022-11-25: To mark start and end sections with ">>>" and "<<<", you can use:

```
sed -e 's/\r/\n/g' temp.log | sed "s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]section_start:[0-9]*:, >>> ,g;s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]section_end:[0-9]*:, <<< ,g;s,section_end:[0-9]*:, <<< ,g;s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g;s,\x0D\x0A,\x0A,g"
```

This will leave you with a plain text file, including the section markers.

```
Running with gitlab-runner x.x.x (xxxxxxxx)
  on generic-runner@doesntexistyet.nl yyyyyyyy
 >>> resolve_secrets
Resolving secrets
 <<< resolve_secrets
 >>> prepare_executor
Preparing the "shell" executor
Using Shell executor...
 <<< prepare_executor
 >>> prepare_script
Preparing environment
Running on doesntexistyet.nl...
 <<< prepare_script
 >>> get_sources
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /<redacted>/.git/
Checking out 12345678 as main...
Removing old.log
Removing temp.log
Skipping Git submodules setup
 <<< get_sources
 >>> step_script
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
$ echo "Hello World!"
Hello World!
 <<< step_script
 >>> cleanup_file_variables
Cleaning up file based variables
 <<< cleanup_file_variables
Job succeeded
```

For a workaround, see: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1950

> Workaround: set *log_format = "text"* in the runner's *config.toml*.

Example:

```
concurrent = 8
check_interval = 0
log_format = "text"

[[runners]]
  executor = "shell"
  ....
```

Comment: Hi @dsnpevl! GitLab support uses [this regex](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support/toolbox/dotfiles/-/blob/main/aliases/ansi) to remove ANSI codes.

Since the docs weren't quite clear about that, I've started [gitlab-runner!3739](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/merge_requests/3739/diffs). Thanks for the prompts here!

[section_start & section_end](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support/toolbox/list-slowest-job-sections/) can be useful for CI performance analysis ;-)

Comment: @KatrinLeinweber Thanks for the feedback! I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi @KatrinLeinweber, give this a try. It replaces section_start with " >>> " and section_end with " <<< ". Maybe recommend to Gitlab support?

sed -e 's/\r/\n/g' temp.log | sed "s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]section_start:[0-9]*:, >>> ,g;s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]section_end:[0-9]*:, <<< ,g;s,section_end:[0-9]*:, <<< ,g;s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g;s,\x0D\x0A,\x0A,g"