# How to get gitlab failed job summary by using gitlab API

Tags: c#, api, gitlab

[image]

How to get the displayed failed job log summary by using gitlab API.
I have trace API which return the complete raw log but i want to get the failed job error details. Does anyone knows how to get the data ?

```
        Gitlab API to get the raw log : 
     https://gitlab.dell.com/api/v4/projects/110506/jobs/80341714/trace
```

Comment: How is this a C# question? This seems very similar to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72889862/how-to-remove-special-characters-from-gitlab-trace-log-api?noredirect=1#comment128762305_72889862).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I want to get the failed job error details"? What information other than the job log do you need?